# Ubuntu system infected with virus, need help with removal and security

Tags: networking, server, malware, chkrootkit

[image]

I accidentally exposed my SSH to the public internet with a user that had a very simple password. Hackers exploited this, and now whenever I boot up and connect to the network, my CPU usage jumps to **100%**

Ubuntu version:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

### `chkrootkit` log:

```
root@server05:~# chkrootkit
ROOTDIR is `/'
Checking `amd'...                                           not found
Checking `basename'...                                      not infected
Checking `biff'...                                          not found
Checking `chfn'...                                          not infected
Checking `chsh'...                                          not infected
Checking `cron'...                                          not infected
Checking `crontab'...                                       not infected
Checking `date'...                                          not infected
Checking `du'...                                            not infected
Checking `dirname'...                                       not infected
Checking `echo'...                                          not infected
Checking `egrep'...                                         not infected
Checking `env'...                                           not infected
Checking `find'...                                          not infected
Checking `fingerd'...                                       not found
Checking `gpm'...                                           not found
Checking `grep'...                                          not infected
Checking `hdparm'...                                        not infected
Checking `su'...                                            not infected
Checking `ifconfig'...                                      not found
Checking `inetd'...                                         not tested
Checking `inetdconf'...                                     not found
Checking `identd'...                                        not found
Checking `init'...                                          not infected
Checking `killall'...                                       not infected
Checking `ldsopreload'...                                   not infected
Checking `login'...                                         not infected
Checking `ls'...                                            not infected
Checking `lsof'...                                          not infected
Checking `mail'...                                          not found
Checking `mingetty'...                                      not found
Checking `netstat'...                                       not found
not found
Checking `named'...                                         not found
Checking `passwd'...                                        not infected
Checking `pidof'...                                         not infected
Checking `pop2'...                                          not found
Checking `pop3'...                                          not found
Checking `ps'...                                            not infected
Checking `pstree'...                                        not infected
Checking `rpcinfo'...                                       not found
Checking `rlogind'...                                       not found
Checking `rshd'...                                          not found
Checking `slogin'...                                        not infected
Checking `sendmail'...                                      not found
Checking `sshd'...                                          not infected
Checking `syslogd'...                                       not tested
Checking `tar'...                                           not infected
Checking `tcpd'...                                          not found
Checking `tcpdump'...                                       not infected
Checking `top'...                                           not infected
Checking `telnetd'...                                       not found
Checking `timed'...                                         not found
Checking `traceroute'...                                    not found
Checking `vdir'...                                          not infected
Checking `w'...                                             not infected
Checking `write'...                                         not infected
Checking `aliens'...                                        no suspect files
Searching for sniffer's logs, it may take a while...        nothing found
Searching for rootkit HiDrootkit's default files...         nothing found
Searching for rootkit t0rn's default files...               nothing found
Searching for t0rn's v8 defaults...                         nothing found
Searching for rootkit Lion's default files...               nothing found
Searching for rootkit RSHA's default files...               nothing found
Searching for rootkit RH-Sharpe's default files...          nothing found
Searching for Ambient's rootkit (ark) default files and dirs... nothing found
Searching for suspicious files and dirs, it may take a while... The following suspicious files and directories were found:
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/.registry
/usr/lib/modules/6.2.0-39-generic/vdso/.build-id
/usr/lib/modules/6.5.0-25-generic/vdso/.build-id

Searching for LPD Worm files and dirs...                    nothing found
Searching for Ramen Worm files and dirs...                  nothing found
Searching for Maniac files and dirs...                      nothing found
Searching for RK17 files and dirs...                        nothing found
Searching for Ducoci rootkit...                             nothing found
Searching for Adore Worm...                                 nothing found
Searching for ShitC Worm...                                 nothing found
Searching for Omega Worm...                                 nothing found
Searching for Sadmind/IIS Worm...                           nothing found
Searching for MonKit...                                     nothing found
Searching for Showtee...                                    nothing found
Searching for OpticKit...                                   nothing found
Searching for T.R.K...                                      nothing found
Searching for Mithra...                                     nothing found
Searching for OBSD rk v1...                                 nothing found
Searching for LOC rootkit...                                nothing found
Searching for Romanian rootkit...                           nothing found
Searching for HKRK rootkit...                               nothing found
Searching for Suckit rootkit...                             nothing found
Searching for Volc rootkit...                               nothing found
Searching for Gold2 rootkit...                              nothing found
Searching for TC2 Worm default files and dirs...            nothing found
Searching for Anonoying rootkit default files and dirs...   nothing found
Searching for ZK rootkit default files and dirs...          nothing found
Searching for ShKit rootkit default files and dirs...       nothing found
Searching for AjaKit rootkit default files and dirs...      nothing found
Searching for zaRwT rootkit default files and dirs...       nothing found
Searching for Madalin rootkit default files...              nothing found
Searching for Fu rootkit default files...                   nothing found
Searching for ESRK rootkit default files...                 nothing found
Searching for rootedoor...                                  nothing found
Searching for ENYELKM rootkit default files...              nothing found
Searching for common ssh-scanners default files...          nothing found
Searching for Linux/Ebury - Operation Windigo ssh...        nothing found
Searching for 64-bit Linux Rootkit ...                      nothing found
Searching for 64-bit Linux Rootkit modules...               nothing found
Searching for Mumblehard Linux ...                          nothing found
Searching for Backdoor.Linux.Mokes.a ...                    nothing found
Searching for Malicious TinyDNS ...                         nothing found
Searching for Linux.Xor.DDoS ...                            INFECTED: Possible Malicious Linux.Xor.DDoS installed
/tmp/par-726f6f74/cache-3eb4257c2614b4554108c1d8497b4f88676951d4/ce30f172.so
/tmp/par-726f6f74/cache-3eb4257c2614b4554108c1d8497b4f88676951d4/9361c2fa.so
/tmp/par-726f6f74/cache-3eb4257c2614b4554108c1d8497b4f88676951d4/libperl.so.5.26/tmp/par-726f6f74/cache-3eb4257c2614b4554108c1d8497b4f88676951d4/f985f8e7.so
/tmp/par-726f6f74/cache-3eb4257c2614b4554108c1d8497b4f88676951d4/f8174441.so
/tmp/par-726f6f74/cache-3eb4257c2614b4554108c1d8497b4f88676951d4/2dfd2f51.so
/tmp/par-726f6f74/cache-3eb4257c2614b4554108c1d8497b4f88676951d4/a8f7a01a.so
/tmp/par-726f6f74/cache-3eb4257c2614b4554108c1d8497b4f88676951d4/5e43fe49.so
/tmp/par-726f6f74/cache-3eb4257c2614b4554108c1d8497b4f88676951d4/85600e38.so
/tmp/par-726f6f74/cache-3eb4257c2614b4554108c1d8497b4f88676951d4/9d18cbe5.so
/tmp/par-726f6f74/cache-3eb4257c2614b4554108c1d8497b4f88676951d4/153152bb.so
/tmp/par-726f6f74/cache-3eb4257c2614b4554108c1d8497b4f88676951d4/neo
Searching for Linux.Proxy.1.0 ...                           nothing found
Searching for CrossRAT ...                                  nothing found
Searching for Hidden Cobra ...                              nothing found
Searching for Rocke Miner ...                               nothing found
Searching for PWNLNX4 lkm...                                nothing found
Searching for PWNLNX6 lkm...                                nothing found
Searching for Umbreon lrk...                                nothing found
Searching for Kinsing.a backdoor...                         nothing found
Searching for RotaJakiro backdoor...                        nothing found
Searching for suspect PHP files...                          nothing found
Searching for anomalies in shell history files...           nothing found
Checking `asp'...                                           not infected
Checking `bindshell'...                                     not infected
Checking `lkm'...                                           You have    85 process hidden for readdir command
You have    86 process hidden for ps command
chkproc: Warning: Possible LKM Trojan installed
chkdirs: nothing detected
Checking `rexedcs'...                                       not found
Checking `sniffer'...                                       Output from ifpromisc:
lo: not promisc and no packet sniffer sockets
eno1: PACKET SNIFFER(/usr/sbin/NetworkManager[1444])
br-9f72851b7f84: not promisc and no packet sniffer sockets
br-9fcc38708952: not promisc and no packet sniffer sockets
br-b3904d96ba80: not promisc and no packet sniffer sockets
br-1e561120853a: not promisc and no packet sniffer sockets
br-280249c410b8: not promisc and no packet sniffer sockets
br-2813e1e9832d: not promisc and no packet sniffer sockets
br-6fbfc16049db: not promisc and no packet sniffer sockets
br-c347269b1b1e: not promisc and no packet sniffer sockets
br-e7e5a438b986: not promisc and no packet sniffer sockets
br-ec3138220ad2: not promisc and no packet sniffer sockets
br-f2e4e371a4a2: not promisc and no packet sniffer sockets
br-2488d2d42884: not promisc and no packet sniffer sockets
br-3c3c0e4d6e35: not promisc and no packet sniffer sockets
br-6a7b5a524719: not promisc and no packet sniffer sockets
br-83e21c81a502: not promisc and no packet sniffer sockets
br-d74348c70ebd: not promisc and no packet sniffer sockets
br-e791ba0df222: not promisc and no packet sniffer sockets
br-fb4dffc78e19: not promisc and no packet sniffer sockets
br-13bd7a801b72: not promisc and no packet sniffer sockets
br-2dca4b8763f4: not promisc and no packet sniffer sockets
br-5f4ea05e7ce9: not promisc and no packet sniffer sockets
br-cdeb38f6243a: not promisc and no packet sniffer sockets
br-83ab3c84f309: not promisc and no packet sniffer sockets
Checking `w55808'...                                        not infected
Checking `wted'...                                          chkwtmp: nothing deleted
Checking `scalper'...                                       not infected
Checking `slapper'...                                       not infected
Checking `z2'...                                            chklastlog: nothing deleted
Checking `chkutmp'...                                       The tty of the following process(es) was not found in /var/run/utmp:
! RUID          PID TTY    CMD
! user         2798 tty2   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -nolisten tcp -background none -noreset -keeptty -novtswitch -verbose 3
! user         2796 tty2   /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session --run-script env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu /usr/bin/gnome-session --session=ubuntu
! user         2928 tty2   /usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --session=ubuntu
chkutmp: nothing deleted
Checking `OSX_RSPLUG'...                                    not tested
```

#### ClamAV log

```bash
root@server05:~# freshclam
ERROR: Can't open/parse the config file /usr/local/etc/freshclam.conf
root@server05:~# clamscan /
LibClamAV Error: cl_load(): No such file or directory: /usr/local/share/clamav
ERROR: Can't get file status

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 0
Engine version: 1.3.0
Scanned directories: 0
Scanned files: 0
Infected files: 0
Data scanned: 0.00 MB
Data read: 0.00 MB (ratio 0.00:1)
Time: 0.003 sec (0 m 0 s)
Start Date: 2024:03:12 23:24:16
End Date:   2024:03:12 23:24:16
root@server05:~# clamscan -r /
LibClamAV Error: cl_load(): No such file or directory: /usr/local/share/clamav
ERROR: Can't get file status
```

Comment: I would simply nuke and reformat the server from scratch.  It looks like the hackers have gotten access to your osystem at an elevated status, and the simpler solution is to simply wipe your server and restart everything.

Comment: "The only way to be certain that you've got control of the system is to rebuild the system"  ----> https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Comment: Your provided details also show you've not applied all security fixes..   so I'll suggest updating your system more regularly  (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/02/22/ubuntu-22-04-4-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date of 22.04.4, but installed systems upgraded **before** that date!)   I'd follow prior advice as to you issue, but monitor & apply upgrades more carefully next time please.